# Can zk-snark proof generation be parallelised across multiple parties in a trustless manner

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Can multiple parties using the same snark protocol, the same verification strings, inputs etc, generate separate proofs and then combine the proof strings somehow to get a proof of the desired strength?

I am interested in whether this is possible in theory, and also in practice using libsnark.